# How to set a dynamic setIcon on a JRadioButton

Tags: java

I've some issues with my code for studies, it's our first time with Java and I don't know how to change the icon of JRadioButtons contents in an array.

```
package exo_02_01;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ControleEtiquette extends JToolBar {

private ImageIcon[] m_iconesBoutons = new ImageIcon[18];
private JRadioButton[] m_boutons = new JRadioButton[6];
private String m_nomsIcones[] = { "bhgauche", "bhcentre", "bhdroite", "bvhaut", "bvcentre", "bvbas" };

private static final int NUMBER_BUTTONS = 6;

public ControleEtiquette() {
    super();
    chargerIcones();
    creerBoutons();
}

private void chargerIcones() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_BUTTONS; i++) {
        m_iconesBoutons[i] = new ImageIcon("RESGRAF/" + m_nomsIcones[i] + ".gif");
        m_iconesBoutons[i + NUMBER_BUTTONS] = new ImageIcon("RESGRAF/" + m_nomsIcones[i] + "R.gif");
        m_iconesBoutons[i + NUMBER_BUTTONS * 2] = new ImageIcon("RESGRAF/" + m_nomsIcones[i] + "B.gif");
    }
}

private void creerBoutons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_boutons.length; ++i) {
        m_boutons[i] = new JRadioButton(m_iconesBoutons[i]);
        add(m_boutons[i]);
        m_boutons[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(m_iconesBoutons[0]);
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(m_iconesBoutons[NUMBER_BUTTONS * 2 - 1]);
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(m_iconesBoutons[5]);
            }
        });
        if (i == 2)
            addSeparator();
    }
}
```

My code in my chargerBoutons() method work well, but my aim is to set the icon according to the current button. I tried to do like

```
((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(m_iconesBoutons[i]);
```

But i is undefined in this scope.

How can I fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: It's now OK : I fix it by creating a variable in the for loop that take i value. And this var can be call from mouseXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you set the icon correctly, but you have to ask for an update of the UI...

So add the call `updateUI()` at the end of your `creerBoutons`method. (it apply on the toolbar (ie: your object).

see [JToolbar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html)